# How to get a list of all block placed by context before running hook_block

Tags: 6, blocks

I'm building a module that manages ad units in the form of blocks that all need to be aware of each other. [Similar to this fellow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8673773/in-drupal-7-how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-blocks-being-used-on-the-page)

I need a simple hook or function to get a listing of every block in all the contexts that will be used on the page before I render my blocks, so I can be sure to know the entire list of ad units on the page.

I've tried this

```
function gpads_sister_positions() {
    $cinstance = context_get_plugin('reaction', 'block');   
    global $theme;

    $all_regions = system_region_list($theme);

    $newblocks = array();

    foreach (array_keys($all_regions) as $region) {
        $n  = $cinstance->block_list($region);
     //   dsm($n,"$region");
        $newblocks = $newblocks + $n;
    }
   // dsm($newblocks,"newblocks");
  return $newblocks;

}
```

I then call this from inside the hook_block in the view op section, like so,

```
function gpads_block($op = 'list', $delta = 0, $edit = array()) {
      switch ($op) {

        // generate a block for each ad position with 'Provide Block' checked
        case 'list':
            ...
          return $blocks;

        case 'view':
        gpads_sister_positions();
        ...
```

THE PROBLEM, is that the function $cinstance->block_list returns different value depending upon the loop of the hook_blocks view. It's as if the block_list function need hook_block to be finished rendering the view stage of all block before it can return an accurate list.

To me this seems crazy, so I am probably just doing something wrong.

Comment: Have you thought about generating placeholders where all the ads can potentially be placed, then populating the placeholders in the theme layer instead?

Comment: James,That is the system we have just moved away from. Thanks for the thought but this is the problem I need to solve.